# calling private functions within class to watch list in Python Visual Studio Code Debugger

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, private

Like the title says, is there a way to call private functions to the watch list in visual studio code?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the debugger a private var or private function is a bit name mangled.

They have added the class name in front of it.

Use the following version of `calledFunc` and step into it with the debugger and inspect the variable `x`

```
  def calledFunc(self):
    x = dir(self)
    x = self.__privateFunc()
    return x
```

x =

```
['_Foo__privateFunc', '_Foo__privateVar', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', ...]
```

Add a watch for:

```
self._Foo__privateFunc()
```